# Does Plotly provide custom graph selection option for different graphs

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

I want to add option where user can select different column and different graph ( line, bar, scatter etc) selection option. Similar to below image -

[image]

One option is I create a custom selection option. But I am not sure if plotly has any inbuilt facility to add such functionality. Please assist if someone knows.

Comment: You can update certain chart properties via custom buttons, see https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/

Comment: @mit: Thanks mit, I am still trying to figure is there any way for custom graph feature selection option as in image is avaulable or not.